# Question about a nested radical identity of Ramanujan involving $\sqrt 5$

Tags: sequences-and-series, nested-radicals

Ramanujan stated this radical in his lost notebook:

$$\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5-\cdots}}}}}}} = \frac{2+\sqrt 5 +\sqrt{15-6\sqrt 5}}{2}$$

Where the pattern of the signs is $++-+++-++++-+++++-\cdots$

I do not have access to his lost notebook.
I wonder how we can prove this.

For periodic sign changes this kind of question is easy but for nonperiodic Im clueless.

Comment: Is this different than: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515253/how-to-prove-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-dots ?

Comment: Is cocopuffs right or not ?

Comment: I have no idea.