# Finding the roots of an octic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I'm trying to solve a problem, but it involves finding the exact roots of the octic polynomial

$$x^8+4x^7-10x^6-54x^5+9x^4+226x^3+125x^2-301x-269$$

How can I find the roots of an octic? Wolfram Alpha just gives me the rounded values. Not the exact ones.

Comment: In general, there is no closed form for the roots of a generic polynomial of degree greater than or equal to five.  You might get lucky and it will factor simply, but such occurrences are rare.  See the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).

Comment: So there is quite a large possibility that there is no way to write the roots of this polynomial in terms of radicals?

Comment: Correct. Most equations of degree five or higher do NOT have roots that can be expressed by radicals and rational numbers.

Comment: Rats... =( This isn't a homework assignment by the way

Comment: It is irreducible over the rationals. Not much to be done; not just a lack of rational roots, if there were anything nice about the roots, it would be possible to factor this. It does factor over the real numbers as a product of quadratics and linears, but those coefficients cannot be found either.

Comment: Okay, thanks...

Comment: A bit of extra-context wouldn't hurt anyone. By chance, is that polynomial involved in some integral?

Comment: Hey Jack; No... I need to find the roots of it to find $x$ in $x=\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+x}}}}$

Comment: Maybe it helps to rewrite it as $$x (x-1) \left( x \left( x (x+1) \left( x (x^2+4 x-9)-50  \right)+176 \right) + 301 \right) - 269 = 0 $$

Comment: @mathguy:This particular octic is solvable in radicals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root $x=1.87178\dots$ is a root of the quadratic,

$$4x^2+2\Big(2-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{13-4\sqrt{5}}\Big)x-\Big(7+5\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{118-50\sqrt{5}}\Big)=0$$

which can then be solved using the well-known quadratic formula.

You can factor your octic into two quartics over $\sqrt{5}$, then those quartics into four quadratics over $\sqrt{13\pm4\sqrt{5}}\,$ (like the above), but you'll need *Mathematica* or *Maple* for a quick result.

Comment: The general case $x = \sqrt{a\pm \sqrt{a\pm \sqrt{a\pm \sqrt{a\pm\dots}}}}$ with period $4$ is discussed in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515253/how-to-prove-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-cdots). Yours is the case $a=5$.

Comment: Wait, but according to the post, how will you know which root to take as the answer to the infinitely nested radical? There are $16$ possible roots, and only $1$ of them are correct...

Comment: @Frank: All of them can be correct, but you have to match it properly to the sign changes you choose. For example, the exact solutions to, $$x_1 = \sqrt{5- \sqrt{5- \sqrt{5+ \sqrt{5+x_1}}}}$$ $$x_2 = -\sqrt{5+ \sqrt{5+ \sqrt{5- \sqrt{5+x_2}}}}$$ are the two roots of the quadratic given in the answer, or $x_1\approx 1.8717$, and $x_2\approx -2.7606$. Which goes with what is primarily by inspection.

Comment: :O Okay, that helps a lot!

Comment: Strictly speaking, the quartics are not over $\mathbb Z[\sqrt5]$. As often happens when the radicand is one greater than a multiple of 4, you get algebraic integers with half-integer components, thus $\mathbb Z[\tau],\tau=(1+\sqrt5)/2$. In terms of this we identify a factor $x^4-(2\tau-3)x^3-(5\tau+2)x^2+(2\tau-1)x+(15\tau-4)$ containing the root.