# Factoring a general biquartic into two quartics

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, nonlinear-system, quartics

Let $W_0$, $W_1$, $W_2$, and $W_3$ be known real numbers.
I have to solve a biquartic equation:

\begin{equation}
z^8+W_3z^6+W_2z^4+W_1z^2+W_0=0
\notag
\end{equation}

Of course I could solve the quartic for $z^2$ and take the square roots of the solutions.
However, I'm looking for an analytical expression, and I guess that extracting the real and imaginary parts of the square roots of the huge expressions of the quartic solutions would be quite a pain.
Thus I tried to factor the biquartic as in [$8$ System of equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934267/8-system-of-equation) , so I will only have to change some signs in the expressions of the quartics solutions.
Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $E$, $F$, and $G$ be complex numbers to be determined:

\begin{equation}
(z^4+Az^3+(B+C)z^2+(AC+E)z+(F+G))(z^4-Az^3+(B-C)z^2+(AC-E)z+(F-G))=0
\notag
\end{equation}

Expanding it and equating the coefficients of the two equations, I found:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
2B&=W_3+A^2\\
8F&=4W_2-(W_3+A^2)^2+8AE+4C^2\\
\end{split}
\notag
\end{equation}

Inserting these equations in the four remaining ones leads to:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
AC(W_3+A^2)-2AG-2CE&=0\\
AC(4W_2-(W_3+A^2)^2+8AE+4C^2)-8EG&=0\\
(W_3+A^2)(4W_2-(W_3+A^2)^2+8AE+4C^2)+8A^2C^2-8E^2-16CG&=8W_1\\
(4W_2-(W_3+A^2)^2+8AE+4C^2)^2-64G^2&=64W_0\\
\end{split}
\notag
\end{equation}

And this is where I'm stuck. Thus the question is: what are the expressions of $A$, $C$, $E$, and $G$ as functions of the $W_j$ coefficients?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function&ved=2ahUKEwiRkO3snLngAhXOuVkKHeolD00QmhMwFnoECA4QPQ&usg=AOvVaw1IiPIJ20AZ26DwEL_hSX5b.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Can you please tell me where, in the WP article you link, it is dealt with biquartic factoring? Thanks in advance.

Comment: They should have a general solution method, you would get the factors from there.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I think I guess what you mean: if I set $A=0$ and $E=0$, then it will fit with the Descartes method for solving quartics. However, and despite $A=0$ and $E=0$ will satify the first two equations of the last system, is it possible find the general expressions of $A$ and $E$, or to demonstrate that they are necessarily $0$ rather than arbitrarily setting them to $0$? Thanks in advance.