# Cyclical System of Quadratic Equations with Four Unknowns

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Solve this system of equations in ℝ (k ∈ [0,1]):

$\ k-x^2=\ y$

$\ k-y^2=\ z$

$\ k-z^2=\ u$

$\ k-u^2=\ x$

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: I saw the trivial solution (0,0,0,0), then I have tried substitiuin and got the a quation of fourth power with two variables, then I trie to put it into A*B=0 and got that x=(+-1+-sqrt(1+4k))/2.

Comment: Presumably $k$ is a parameter, the remaining variables unknown.  Then for $k\ge(-1/4)$ there will be solutions with $x=y=z=u$.  Can you see that?

Comment: [Related to a problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/625139/4781) considered by Ramanujan.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

1. When $\text{k}-x^2=y$ and $\text{k}-u^2=x$:
   $$\text{k}-\left(\text{k}-u^2\right)^2=y$$
2. When $\text{k}-z^2=u$ and $\text{k}-y^2=z$:
   $$\text{k}-\left(\text{k}-y^2\right)^2=u$$

So:

$$\text{k}-\left(\text{k}-\left(\text{k}-\left(\text{k}-u^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2=u$$

Comment: It woul lead to the equation with u to the power more than ten.

Comment: @LeoBern For example, when $k=0$, then we get: $-u^{16}=u$.

Comment: @JanEerland: Interestingly, Ramanujan considered the related equation$$\text{k}+\left(\text{k}+\left(\text{k}+\left(\text{k}+x^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2=x$$ and solved it in radicals. Kindly see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/625139/4781).

Comment: @LeoBern: Of course, as one has to raise to the $2$nd power four times. Thus you need to solve a factorable $16$-deg equation. Fortunately, Ramanujan did related work. See the link I posted above.