# Ramanujan and his problem

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, nested-radicals

Following was proposed by Ramanujan:

$ \sqrt{11-2\sqrt{11+2\sqrt{11-2\sqrt{11+\cdots}}}}=1+4\sin(10^o)$

Working on this I got the radical on the left equal to $(1+2\sqrt{2})$ implying that $\sin(10^o)=1/\sqrt{2}$

How is this possible? What is wrong here?

Comment: $\sin(\color{red}{45}^o)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ ?

Comment: I think you could show how you obtained $1+2\sqrt{2}$ for the left hand side since that seems to be the issue

Comment: I got $2 \sqrt{2} - 1$ for the LHS.

Comment: @Dando18 Even [W|A](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%2811-2%28sqrt%2811%2B2x%29%29%29%3Dx&x=0&y=0) says that.

Comment: It is a more long for comment but I write it:
$$2\sqrt(2)-1=\sqrt{(2\sqrt(2)-1)^2}=\sqrt{9-4\sqrt(2)}=\sqrt {11-2(2\sqrt(2)+1)}$$
$$=\sqrt {11-2\sqrt {(2\sqrt(2)+1)^2}}=\sqrt {11-2\sqrt {9+4\sqrt(2)}}=\sqrt {11-2\sqrt {11+2(2\sqrt(2)-1)}}$$
$$
=\sqrt {11-2\sqrt {11+2(\sqrt{(2\sqrt(2)-1)^2}}}=\sqrt {11-2\sqrt {11+2\sqrt {11-2\sqrt{\cdots}}}}
$$
Maybe useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\sqrt{11-2\sqrt{11+2\sqrt{11-2\sqrt{11+\cdots}}}}$ and $ y=\sqrt{11+2\sqrt{11-2\sqrt{11+2\sqrt{11-\cdots}}}}$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
x=\sqrt{11-2y} \\
y=\sqrt{11+2x}
\end{eqnarray*}
so $x^2=11-2y$ & $y^2=11+2x$ ... after a little algebra ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^4-22x^2-8x+77=0 \\
(x^2+2x-7)(x^2+2x-11)=0
\end{eqnarray*}
So we have the possible solutions $x=-1 \pm 2 \sqrt{2}$ & $x=1 \pm 2 \sqrt{3}$.
One can verify that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{11-2\sqrt{11+2\sqrt{11-2\sqrt{11+\cdots}}}}=\color{red}{2 \sqrt{2}-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
If the $+$ and $-$'s alternate then the above value is correct ... Ramanujan actually does the $(-,+,-)$ repeating every $3$ times ... then the result is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{11-2\sqrt{11+2\sqrt{11-2\sqrt{11\color{red}{-}\cdots}}}}=1+ \sin(10^o).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: From your solution it reveals that $\sin 10^o = \frac {\sqrt {2} -1} {2} \approx  0.20711$ where as the actual value of $\sin 10^o$ is approximately equal to $0.1736$.Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5):

Actually you have written the identity incorrectly. [The original, by Ramanujan, stated](https://books.google.com/books?id=oSioAM4wORMC&pg=PA329&lpg=PA329&dq=ramanujan+1%2B4sin(10)&source=bl&ots=sP2m9RKzvg&sig=QmDlBkclANtzlXKf_UYDbu9NpTA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNjfzxtrPUAhXFbj4KHf1PCZsQ6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=ramanujan%201%2B4sin(10)&f=false):

$$ 1 + 4\sin 10^\circ = \sqrt{11 - 2\sqrt{11 + 2\sqrt{11 - 2(1 + 4\sin 10^\circ) \dots }}} $$

**Edit:** note the period of signs is $-, +, -, -, +, -, -, +, -, \dots$

or letting $ x = 1 + 4\sin 10^\circ $

$$ x = \sqrt{11 - 2\sqrt{11 + 2\sqrt{11 - 2x \dots }}} $$

According to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%5B11+-+2*sqrt%5B11%2B+2*sqrt%5B11+-+2*x%5D%5D%5D+%3D+x), we have $x \approx 1.695$ and [again](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+4+sin%5B10+deg%5D) $1 + 4 \sin 10^\circ \approx 1.695$

Comment: Try this ... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%5B11+-+2*sqrt%5B11%2B+2*x%5D%5D+%3D+x

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit won't let me follow that link

Comment: @Dando18 you could visit : https://www.google.co.in/url?url=https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ae75/da0be9fb455e2c55daa5fca46ae63e6a60bd.pdf&rct=j&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjizq-CvbPUAhXMRo8KHS-jB2kQFggpMAE&sig2=xJKzJdEKawNUHnFw83UhAA&q=problems+published+by+ramanujan&usg=AFQjCNHBMQq-GgLprHX8m7qQuztDwbjwPg and see page 4

Comment: sqrt[11 - 2*sqrt[11+ 2*x]] = x ... <- input this into Wolfie @Dando18

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I'm not sure what you're implying. The expression in my post is different in signs $-, +, -, -, +, ... $

Comment: @MrigankShekharPathak see the top link I added. and also below number __b__ in your link, it says the period of signs is $-, +, -, -, +, -, -, +, +, \dots$

Comment: @Dando18 ... The OP confused me into thinking the $+$ & $-$ alternated ... You are right, we need to look more carefully at the original result. It repeats every third time ... $(-,+,-)$ !

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Ramanujan's above formula, I added some similar results here:

$ $

$ 4 \cos \left(\frac{4 \pi }{9}\right)+1=\sqrt{11-2 \sqrt{11+2 \sqrt{11-2 \left(4 \cos \left(\frac{4 \pi }{9}\right)+1\right)}}} $

$ 4 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{9}\right)+1=\sqrt{11+2 \sqrt{11-2 \sqrt{11-2 \left(4 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{9}\right)+1\right)}}} $

$ 4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)-1=\sqrt{11-2 \sqrt{11-2 \sqrt{11+2 \left(4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)-1\right)}}} $

$  $

$ 4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+1=\sqrt{11+2 \sqrt{11-2 \left(4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+1\right)}} $

$ 4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)-1=\sqrt{11-2 \sqrt{11+2 \left(4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)-1\right)}} $

$  $

$ 4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right)+1=\sqrt{11+2 \left(4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right)+1\right)} $

$ 4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right)-1=\sqrt{11-2 \left(4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right)-1\right)} $

$ $

$ 4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+1=\sqrt{7+2 \left(4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+1\right)} $

$ 4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)-1=\sqrt{7-2 \left(4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)-1\right)} $

$ $

Other similar results can be found here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4233146/954936

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4232525/954936

http://eslpower.org

http://eslpower.org/Notebook.htm